# Error in configuring/installation of nodemon

Tags: node.js

I'm new to nodejs, I am having difficulties in setting up nodemon. I tried to install nodemon using the below command

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

But I get the below error,

```
npm WARN package.json methods@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json bytes@0.2.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json pause@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json send@0.1.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json range-parser@0.0.4 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json cookie-signature@1.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json fresh@0.1.0 No repository field.
```

How to solve this? And How do I configure nodemon to monitor changes to my files?

Comment: This has nothing to do with nodemon. I'm getting the same warnings for the same repositories which I think Express is using them. The authors of those modules should add repository url to their package.json. Take a look at here for more info: https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html but simply this doesn't concern you.  Just a simple accurate warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The messages you're getting are just warnings emitted by npm to warn that the installed package.json has no repository specified. This behavior of npm is quite new. See [this github issue](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/3446).

The good news is, you have nodemon installed successfully and you do not need to configure it but start it with some command line options. See the [nodemon page](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) for more information.

A simple usage example is

```
nodemon --watch routes app.js
```

Which starts app.js and watches the routes directory for changes.